# Node-postgres - Flattening query result array

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, multidimensional-array, flatten

I want to get a array of ids from my database table as a one-dimensional array.

I've used QueryArrayConfig for my query string with the rowMode set to "array". I get my ids correctly, but it returns a two-dimensional array.

```
            const idQuery: pg.QueryArrayConfig = {
                name: 'get-ids',
                text: 'SELECT id FROM MySchema.SomeTable'
                rowMode: "array"
            };

            pool.query(idQuery).then((result: pg.QueryResult) => {
                console.log(result.rows);
                ...
```

I get : `[ [ 1 ], [ 2 ] ]`, but I need `[1 , 2]`. **Is there a way to do this with my query directly?** Or do I need to flatten my array *after* I get my results?

**Edit** : 
If I remove `rowMode: array`, I get an array of javascript objects : `[anonymous { id: 1 }, anonymous { id: 2 }]`, which doesn't give me what I need.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `rowMode` of 'Array' it will return each row as an individual array as per the docs https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#Query%20config%20object . The default is to return each one as an object, so just remove the `rowMode:"array"` line and see if that works.

With the object you can use `map` or the array you can use a simple `flatMap` on your original results

```
let results = result.flatMap(row => row); // for the array or array results
let results = result.map(item => item.id); // for the object results
```

Comment: If I remove `rowMode: array`, I get an array of javascript objects : `[ anonymous { id: 1 }, anonymous { id: 2 } ]`

Comment: Well it's either going to return an array of objects or an array of arrays, so it comes down to what you prefer working with